# Dodge Ram engine stopped when making right turn

Tags: engine, dodge, ram

I have a 2005 Dodge Ram.  I was making a right turn and the whole engine stopped, brakes seized and the wheel locked.  Then it started right back up,  It seems to be fine now.  There is no check engine light of code or anything. I had just overfilled my tank.  Wondering if this could be it?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Did the car start itself, or did you turn the key?  Also, I'm assuming this is an automatic transmission?

Answer (score 1):

Don't overfill your tank, but I'm 99% sure that's not it. The tank's in the rear of the car and all an overfilled tank could do is leak, which in the rear wouldn't cause this by any means. Maybe some rust is all. (And there's the environment, but that motivation differs by person ;))

The only thing I can think of is something to do with the ignition/electrical/computer system.  If the car thought the ignition (key) was turned off, it would obviously stop the engine (check), and since you were turning, the wheel would be locked (check).  I don't think the brakes would lock in this case though.  Are you sure it wasn't the transmission still engaged, and slowing the car down?  That might do it.

I don't think there should be anything that could cause the breaks to actually lock, unless your truck is pretty smart (the newer ones are).  The closest thing would be the car putting itself in Park (which obviously shouldn't be able to happen, but sometimes things don't work like they should).  What Park does is lock the transmission, so there might or might not be a huge difference between this and simply turning off the car while you're in drive.